# What's the longest a safeTransaction can be in pending state after execution?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have a safe transaction that's been pending for 30+ mins despite the actual eth transaction being completed 30 mins ago. I can't get the eth transaction hash associated with the transaction either through the gnosis transaction API or UI.

https://gnosis-safe.io/app/rin:0x0b82E5Da52D1AaACaF8B67742aF4328f69E41427/transactions/0x63fb57e0610552d2859188bb2d2053e4fe38fe52ae2e17f539e497b428bc3cf5

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x549e23563c0a58f8f5e8fc22410b7af80e4c30704d5482ebfc9706d710cb2ced

what's the longest this state can be inconsistent for? would it be faster on the mainnet?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently a [known issue](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-react/issues/3440) that if a transaction fails, it remains pending in the UI. We are actively looking into fixing this.

For the time being, if you clear your `sessionStorage` and refresh the page or close/reopen your browser, the pending status will reset.